# Сравнение двух строк с разной последовательностью слов

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, сравнение

Есть две строки, которые по своей сути (почти) идентичны. Пример

```
s1 = "Variant 2 IBC-Solar Module + 1x SMA WR Stand - Eon Aura 19.01.2017"

s2 = "19.01.2017 Variant 2 IBC-Solar Module + 1 x SMA WR Stand - Eon Aura Some Extra Words"
```

Можно заметить, что в этих строках пости все слова одинаковые. Какую метрику можно применить для сравнения этих строк? 
`difflib` не предлагать. Нужно просто определить, какая часть совпадает и какие отличия. То есть должна быть метрика, которая, *например* скажет что 80% слов совпадают и вторая строка больше первой.

1. Пробовал переводить строки в списки и сравнивать элементы,
2. Пробовал применять множество, но это не корректно, поскольку в одной сроке может быть несколько одинаковх слов, в другой могут **не** повторяться.

Визуально они выглядят одинаково, т.е. содержат одинаковые элементы, последовательность их не так важна. Однако, например в первой строке написано `1x`, а во второй`1 x`

Как быть?

Comment: Расстояние Левенштейна?

Comment: Как насчет такого: разделить на слова, подсчитать слова (в словаре ключ-слово, значение-количество), сравнить по ключам и, например, количеством?

Comment: @gil9red думал с символами так сделать, со словами не получится - в предпоследний строчке объяснение маленькое

Comment: Ищите алгоритмы word diff. Дальше немного доработать напильником.